# WooCommerce and DIBS pretty permalinks 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks, dibs

I'm creating a wordpress webshop using WooCommerce and DIBS. 
When payment is done, and you click for your receipt, the site redirects you to /woocommerce/dibsaccept and I get a 404 error, causing payment to fail.

I think it might be a problem with the permalinks, but I don't really understand how or where to fix this problem.

Could someone explain this to me, like I was a child :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in your web server root? What web server are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have a .htaccess file. I don't know which web server, how do I check that?